# Proving an inequality related to Riemann integration

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

**Problem**

> Let $f$ be a function such that $|f(u)-f(v)| \leq |u-v|$.
>   Assume that $f$ is integrable on $[a,b]$. 
>   Prove that 
>   $$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx - (b-a)f(c)\right| \leq (b-a)^2/2$$
>   where $c\in [a,b]$

**Attempt**

It is easy to prove that $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$   (uniformly).

Now since $f$ is continuous on a compact set, it attains its extremum in that set. So it is bounded. Say $|f(x)| \leq M$ where $M=f(c')$ for some $c\in [a,b]$.
Now, 
$$\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x)dx - (b-a)f(c)\right| \leq |(f(c')-f(c))(b-a)| \leq (b-a)^2.$$
Why I am missing $1/2$?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need the maximum of $f$. For *all* $c \in [a, b]$
$$
\left|\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx - (b-a)f(c)  \right| =
\left|\int_{a}^{b} (f(x)-f(c)) \, dx \right| \\\le
\int_{a}^{b} | f(x) - f(c) | \, dx \le
\int_{a}^{b} | x-c | \, dx \\
= \int_{a}^{c} (c-x) \, dx + \int_{c}^{b} (x-c) \, dx \\
= \frac{(c-a)^2}{2} +  \frac{(b-c)^2}{2} \\ \le  \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}
$$

Comment: How did you get the last inequality?

Comment: @blueboy: $x^2 + y^2 \le (x+y)^2$ for nonnegative numbers. You can also see it geometrically if you draw the triangles corresponding to these areas.

Comment: Oh.  Thanks. When i used the maximum it wasn't using the required bound.

Answer (score 0):

Let $c=\frac {a+b} 2$. Note that $\int_a^{b} [f(x)-f(c)]dx=\int_a^{b} f(x)dx-f(c)(b-a)$. Hence $|\int_a^{b} f(x)dx-f(c)(b-a)| \leq \int_a^{b} |f(x)-f(c)|dx \leq \int_a^{b} |x-c|dx$. calculate this last integal explicitly by making the change of variable $y=x-c$ and you will get the desired inequality.